# Pandas indexing item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to find the corrispective of an element in another column of a Pandas DataFrame.
The DataFrame is like this:

```
EVENT        CODE          DAY
event01      102934        00/00/0000
event02      021384        00/00/0000
event03      045823        00/00/0000
```

My script is like this:

```
for a in df["EVENT"]:
    print(a + " " + code)

//event01 102934
//event02 021384
//event03 045823
```

For example I would like to find out what is the code associated to the event03 (so 045823). How can I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simpliest is [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `EVENT` and then select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.set_index('EVENT')
print (df)
           CODE         DAY
EVENT                      
event01  102934  00/00/0000
event02  021384  00/00/0000
event03  045823  00/00/0000
```

For unique values of `CODE` are unique it return scalar:

```
print (df.loc['event01', 'CODE'])
102934

print (df.loc['event02', 'CODE'])
021384

print (df.loc['event02', 'DAY'])
00/00/0000
```

But if multiple values it return [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series):

```
df = df.set_index('EVENT')
print (df)
           CODE         DAY
EVENT                      
event01  103453  00/00/0000
event01  102934  00/00/0000
event02  021384  00/00/0000
event03  045823  00/00/0000

print (df.loc['event01', 'CODE'])
EVENT
event01    103453
event01    102934
Name: CODE, dtype: object
```

For looping you can use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for i, x in df.iterrows():
    print (x['EVENT'] + ' ' + x['CODE'])

event01 102934
event02 021384
event03 045823
```

Comment: What does "set_index" do?

Comment: It means create helper labels for fast selecting from column - check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for better explanation.

Comment: How can I iterate print(event + " " + code) for each element in column?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter out all other events and then returning the requested attribute by simply `df[df["Event"]== "event01"]["CODE"]`.

However, if you would like to iterate through all events I would direct you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas).